# Netlogo Extension: Comparing Lists of Strings

Tags: java, netlogo

I´m trying to wrote my first Netlogo extension which can compare to lists of strings, hopefully. As I´m new to writing extension and don´t know much about programming Java I´m hoping for help.

My code so far is:

```
package org.nlogo.extensions.string;

import org.nlogo.api.Argument;
import org.nlogo.api.Context;
import org.nlogo.api.DefaultReporter;
import org.nlogo.api.ExtensionException;
import org.nlogo.api.LogoException;
import org.nlogo.api.Syntax;
import org.nlogo.api.LogoListBuilder;
import org.nlogo.api.LogoList;


public class Matching2 extends DefaultReporter{

@Override
public Syntax getSyntax(){
    return Syntax.reporterSyntax(new int[] { Syntax.ListType(), Syntax.ListType()  },
                                 Syntax.ListType());
}


@Override
public Object report(Argument args[], Context context)
        throws ExtensionException, LogoException
    {
        LogoList input1 = args[0].getList() ;
        LogoList input2 = args[1].getList();
        return input1.retainAll(input2);

    }
```

}

However, I only get an error when I try to run the model...

Thx in advance.

Edit:

```
error (UnsupportedOperationException)
while observer running SHOW
called by procedure CHECK-POTENTIAL-WORDS
called by procedure GO
called by Button 'go one time step'

NetLogo is unable to supply you with more details about this error.Please report the problem at https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues, or to bugs@ccl.northwestern.edu, and paste the contents of this window into your report.

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException at org.nlogo.api.LogoList.org$nlogo$api$LogoList$$unsupported(LogoList.scala:67)
at org.nlogo.api.LogoList$Iterator.remove(LogoList.scala:64)
at org.nlogo.api.LogoList$Iterator.remove(LogoList.scala:54)
at java.util.AbstractCollection.retainAll(AbstractCollection.java:410)
at org.nlogo.extensions.string.Matching2.report(Matching2.java:28)
at org.nlogo.prim._externreport.report(_externreport.java:50)
at org.nlogo.prim.etc._show.perform(_show.scala:13)
at org.nlogo.nvm.Context.stepConcurrent(Context.java:91)
at org.nlogo.nvm.ConcurrentJob.step(ConcurrentJob.java:82)
at     org.nlogo.job.JobThread.org$nlogo$job$JobThread$$runPrimaryJobs(JobThread.scala:143)
 at org.nlogo.job.JobThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobThread.scala:78)
 at org.nlogo.job.JobThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobThread.scala:76)
 at org.nlogo.job.JobThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobThread.scala:76)
 at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:88)
 at org.nlogo.util.Exceptions$.handling(Exceptions.scala:41)
 at org.nlogo.job.JobThread.run(JobThread.scala:75)
```

Comment: WHAT error do you get?

Comment: Could it be an error stating that the remainnig list is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `LogoList` implementation of the `List` interface does not support the `retainAll()` method - that is, because the default implementation of that method, in `AbstractCollection`, uses the iterator's `remove()` method, which is `unsupported` by `LogoList` - see its source code here: https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/blob/c56cffd5b12cf135efc4c3640b3cc0d5dc2acc3c/parser-core/src/main/core/LogoList.scala

Workaround: create your own list objects with an implementation supporting this operation (e.g. `ArrayList`):

```
List input1 = new ArrayList(args[0].getList());
List input2 = new ArrayList(args[1].getList());

input1.retainAll(input2);
return input1;
```

But if you are required to return a `LogoList`, this may not work - try this instead:

```
return new LogoList(input1);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but the result is only a true/false indicating whether elements in list a are in list b (false) or not (true).

Comment: @MatthiasMueller The result is an ArrayList, or a LogoList. Or do you mean it **shall be** only a boolean? It has not been in your initial code as well. Please re-specify your expectations for your method then.

Comment: Hi, I want it to create a List of strings which are in both inputs, yet I get only a boolean (true/false) instead.

Comment: OK, my fault. Didn't get that `retainAll` does not return a collection, but only **alters** the collection. Fixed the code snippet above.

Comment: Thank you so much.